Is there a way to transfer an entire browsing session between different devices?
Let's say that I'm logged into a website on my desktop computer and I'm in the middle of something. Then I need to leave my desk.
I would like to transfer my browsing session (and by that I mean cookies, local storage and any other local state) onto my phone or another device and pick up right from where I left.
By this I mean that I wouldn't have to log in again. I'm aware that some of the local state is in memory (e.g. JavaScript state, the state of form inputs, etc). I'm fine with not being able to transfer that too.
I don't mean to be able to change browser. I'd be perfectly happy to port my session e.g. from Chrome desktop to Chrome mobile or Firefox desktop to Firefox mobile.
Clarification:
I'm not looking for some sort of renote desktop solution.
Ideally the solution would be some browser extension that can take a snapshot of the browser session on a device and move it to another device.

If you have a computer you can dedicate to this task, I would use remote desktop and set it up so that your browser lives in there. That way, you can always connect to that computer from anywhere and continue your browsing session. This will even work on Android, and you can even have some text in an input field, then close the remote connection, connect from somewhere else, and continue typing, just like that. You can also rent a cloud desktop and do it there.

The alternative to RDP, copying all items in the profile, including cookies, cache, etc. would likely be unfeasible. For example, there are slightly different versions of browsers for each OS, with differences as small a s EOL character(s) that would make that problematical.
